# Monomac An Exception as thown by the type initializer for System.Net.WebRequest

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, monomac, app-bundle

I'm writing a program in `monomac` to ftp files to a server. I used the `FtpWebRequest` as

```
FtpWebRequest request =(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://serverip/filename");
```

When I'm running this code in `monodevelop` its running properly. But when I release this and runs outside `monodevelop` I get the error "An Exception as thrown by the type initialize for `System.Net.WebRequest`.

I researched for this error and found it has problem with the library libc.dylib. If I change the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH in launch script of the `app(AppBundle/MacOs/AppName edit with TextEdit)` as

export `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib"`

(added /usr/lib)
then it is sending the files. But I have to install mono framework in all system to run this app. Once i create a mac installer package i cannot edit the the launch script. I tried copying `libc.dylib` file from `/usr/lib` to `Appbundle(App/MonoBundle/)` but still the error exists.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Are you adding monomac dll's to the app bundle?

It tries to be clever and remove unused methods and classes.

I found that it would often not include methods it thought were not being used by mistake.
I'm not sure how to force it to include the missing methods, however you can solve this by turn off linking in the package settings. Unfortunately this makes the app much bigger.